# What is the difference between 'nav' and 'for' for looping?

Tags: categories, navigation, loop

I am new to craftcms and did a look through on the documentation just recently.

I am at the part where it explain about the Categories Field and found out that we can loop through the ElementCriteriaModel with the 'nav' keyword instead of 'for'.

I checked the twig documentation but there are no 'nav' keyword :|

So which one should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for` is [part of the native Twig language](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html).

`for` is for general usage... It's the basic, general looping structure that you'll use 99% of the time. You'll find that it closely mirrors `for` and `foreach` in other programming languages.

---

`nav` is [defined by Craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/nav), and doesn't exist natively in Twig.

`nav` is special... You'll only need it to loop through entries in a [Structure section](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#section-types), or categories in a [Category Group](https://craftcms.com/docs/categories). **The sole purpose of `nav` is to make it easier to create a menu or navigation.**

One of the biggest benefits to using the `nav` tag is that you'll then be able to use `ifchildren` within it...

```
{% ifchildren %}
    <ul>
        {% children %}
    </ul>
{% endifchildren %}
```

The logical relationship between `nav` and its respective `children` is slightly complicated... and worthy of a separate post if you need further clarification. :)